# How to send file with POST request using curl?

Tags: api, curl, post, request, postman

I am trying to send a file using the POST request, with curl:

```
curl -v -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' --data-binary '@test.xml'  'http://localhost:10215/'
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Could not resolve host: application
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Could not resolve host: 'http
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'http
```

Over Postman, I managed to send the file, by adding the file content in the body of the request. But how could I update the curl command, so that I could be able to send the file from the folder I am running the command from? The authentication is basic authentication and the Content-Type of the request must be specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you have achieve it with postman, just copy the curl code that is generated by postman clicking in the code button:

[image: postman]